# Task.Factory.StartNew Run Task in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Im new using threads in C# and even I've been reading the hole day I can't fix this problem:

I have a console app using the framework 4.5 for sending emails, the problem is that even I'm using Task.Factory.StartNew it seem that the app run the threads sequentially and not in parallel.

Anyone can give me some advice?

Note:
The queuedEmails contains a MAX number of 70 emails list

CODE:

```
public void Send()
{
    IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    List<string> logLines = new List<string>();

    foreach (EmailEnt emailEnt in queuedEmails)
    {
        string subject = "I'm the subject";
        string cuerpo_email = "I'm the email body";

        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
                DownloadHtml("http://www.google.com");
                Console.Out.WriteLine("done"+DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
        }));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

  public static string DownloadHtml(string Url)
    {
        // Open a connection
        HttpWebRequest WebRequestObject = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

        // You can also specify additional header values like 
        // the user agent or the referer:

        WebRequestObject.UserAgent = ".NET Framework/2.0";
        WebRequestObject.Referer = "http://www.example.com/";

        // Request response:
        WebResponse Response = WebRequestObject.GetResponse();

        // Open data stream:
        System.IO.Stream WebStream = Response.GetResponseStream();

        // Create reader object:
        System.IO.StreamReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(WebStream);

        // Read the entire stream content:
        string PageContent = Reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Cleanup
        Reader.Close();
        WebStream.Close();
        Response.Close();

        return PageContent;
    }
```

Comment: You are reusing a field called `email`. What type is that?

Comment: Is my own class to send the emails

Comment: Then it would make sense to post that code, otherwise it will be hard to give you solid advice!

Answer (score 3):

De SendMailMessage method cannot be called asynchronous. Thus preparing your mail will be done parallel, but because sending is done sequential your emails will be send one by one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The method calls the AWS SES web service. It doesn't call an SMTP server

Comment: It doesnt matter what server you call, .NET prevents parallel requests on the SendMailMessage call.

Answer (score 1):

If your `SendMailMessage` method uses the `SmtpClient.Send` method, at the MSDN Documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx) it says:

> This method blocks while the e-mail is transmitted.

and also:

> You cannot call this method if there is a message being sent asynchronously.

So it seems you must use another method if you want to send in parallel... However sending synchronously should pose any problems because a good SMTP server can handle outgoing messages quickly (and often does just queue them up).

Comment: I'm not using an SMTP server it's an AWS amazon SES web service.

Comment: See, that's why it is handy to show the code you want people to advise on.

Answer (score -1):

Your email provider, or your network connection to your email provider, likely cannot support a large number of concurrent connections.  It's not abnormal to only allow a few concurrent requests, possibly even only one concurrent request.

If you were doing something other than sending email, you'd likely see some parallelization, but in this case your requests are being synchronized further down the line.

Comment: Yes is amazon SES and it does. Inside the method sendEmails I've written a loop of operations (instead calling a web service) to discard that the problem could be a network issue and it happened the same. They run sequentially

Comment: @RobertoZamora That's also a network related task, and very potentially subject to the same restriction.

Comment: I replaced the invoke to the web service for while(10000000){double a = 12.321321*123.23546} And happened the same behavior.

Comment: @RobertoZamora And how are you observing the fact that these operations aren't paralleized?  Especially in your last example, there are no side effects to observe.

Comment: At the end of the loop there is a Console.Out.WriteLine("DONE");

Comment: @RobertoZamora And how does that prove that they are run sequentially?

Comment: @RobertoZamora Keep in mind that the compiler/JIT can look at that line of code, determine that it provably never does anything, and remove it entirely.  Even if it didn't, a loop like that is going to run *blazingly* fast.  Each thread can potentially finish something like that in a single times slice.